# Is there a way to invoke lambda function when a read replica in a region is promoted to a standalone DB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-event-bridge

hope you all are doing well.
I am undergoing a scenario where i need to trigger a lambda function whenever a read replica is promoted. It shouldn't be a failover scenario every time but I can just manually promote and it should trigger the lambda function.

I have tried creating a event of Cloudtrail, RDS, AWS API Call via Cloudtrail. Nothing helps. I looked into logs and still no luck.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: AWS API Call via CloudTrail should work. Just create an eventbridge rule to trigger a lambda function on PromoteReadReplicaDBCluster or PromoteReadReplica event.

Comment: @jellycsc any prerequisite for creating this event?

Comment: Steps described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-log-api-call.html

Comment: can someone also advise me that how can i wait until that read replica is completely turned into a standalone db instance so afterwards i can apply various lambda on it. Is there a way in anyone to how to achieve that?